# How Flatbuffers works on low level ? how vtable arranges data?

Tags: flatbuffers

I looked up on internet and could only find https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_white_paper.html which doesn't discuss much about in depth details about implementation or how vtable data-structures arranges fields.

Any links/ recourses/ explanations are appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The link just below the one you give is https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_internals.html which is exactly what explains what you're asking for.